# Android Efficiency - Views

Tags: java, android, performance, memory, android-layout

Is it better to `findViewById(<resource-id>)` once and store in the scope of your activity (class-wide) or call the above per use, so that the resources are reclaimed when the current scope/method is exited?

I guess it boils down to how expensive `findViewById()` is compared to how expensive it is to store view objects class-wide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only storing references to views; the storage cost is minimal.  Most quality code I've seen finds the view once for each activity, so I take that as best practice.  Readability and maintainability are just bonuses.

Answer (score 0):

I think the performance difference is imperceptible. More important than that is how your code looks like... is it readable when you populate your activity class with `findViewById` invocations?

Comment: Right, readability is important, but on a mobile device, it seems like attention to performance detail is important, especially on a platform like android with unpredictable hardware driving it.

Comment: Yeah... still no too important. Over-optimization is not good sometimes. Sure, you are talking about devices with limited hardware resources, etc... but you better care about not creating too many objects, manage your bitmaps in an efficient way, etc. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

Comment: I very much agree, so on that note, is calling findViewById multiple times creating multiple objects?

Comment: Not at all... it's just retrieving a reference to an existing object. That's why I say the performance difference must be imperceptible or non-existence.